# Fortran subroutine is not calculating when called by R

Tags: r, fortran, gfortran, subroutine

I have a huge set of data, in a 3D array, so I'm trying to speed calculations in R by use of a Fortran routine. The subroutine below is compiled perfectly by two commands :

```
    gfortran -c -ffree-form file_name.f
    R CMD SHLIB file_name.f
```

Here is my subroutine :

```
    subroutine saturation_vapour_pressure_from_temperature(temp,m,n,o,saturation_vapour_pressure)
    implicit none
    integer :: m,n,o
    integer :: x,y,t
    real, intent(in) ::temp(m,n,o)
    real, intent(out) :: saturation_vapour_pressure(m,n,o)
    real :: lvRv,To,eo
    saturation_vapour_pressure(m,n,o) = temp(m,n,o)
    LvRv= 5234.0
    To= 273.15
    eo= 0.6113
    do 15, t=1,o
        do 10, y=1,n
          do 5, x=1,m
          saturation_vapour_pressure(x,y,t) = eo * exp(LvRv*1/To - LvRv*1/temp(x,y,t))
 5          end do 
10         end do 
15       end do
     end subroutine saturation_vapour_pressure_from_temperature
```

I assigned the same value for the input as output and then perform the calculation by the loop. however it is not working, although I have other subroutines with the same principle and they are working! Here is the call in R.

```
 temperature<-array(runif(12,273.15,300),dim = c(2,3,2))
 DIMn<-dim(temperature)
 #DIMn is the dimension of array
 dyn.load("saturation_vapour_pressure_from_temperature.so")      
result<- array(.Fortran("saturation_vapour_pressure_from_temperature",temp=as.numeric(temperature),
                      m=as.integer(DIMn[1]),
                      n=as.integer(DIMn[2]),
                      o=as.numeric(DIMn[3]),saturation_vapour_pressure=as.numeric(temperature))$saturation_vapour_pressure,
             dim = DIMn)
```

when I check the values

```
   $ all(temperature==result)
     [1] TRUE
```

Comment: What do you mean 'it is not working'? Does it crash, does it give the wrong output, does it throw an exception (I assume that R has exceptions)?

Comment: No errors at all , it is just not calculating. it does not change the output array values @chw21

Comment: have you tried declaring the `saturation_vapour_pressure` as `real, intent(out) :: saturation_vapour_pressure(m, n, o)`?

Comment: I have tried it now! Still not calculating, Maybe it is the mathematical expression? I'm not well acquainted with that in FORTRAN

Comment: Please show a full [mcve] in R where we can see the incorrect output. And show the **exact** copy of your Fortran code you are compiling. The code you are showing now cannot compile because `s` is not declared.

Comment: `o=as.numeric` is a typo: it should be `o=as.integer` as with the other arguments.

Comment: Why are you multiplying `LvRv` by `1` in `exp()`?

Comment: It was a typo as @francescalus mentioned, Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not well versed in R, but I can give you a few ideas:

1. The code that you have there shouldn't compile, as you don't declare the variable `s`. I suspect that the first do loop should use `t`, not `s` as the iterator, but you'd know this better.
   Is it possible that it's failing to compile and you're using an old version?
2. You don't need to use labels. Just type

   ```
   do t = 1, o
       do y = 1, n
           do x = 1, m
               saturation_vapour_pressure(x,y,t) = eo * exp(LvRv*1/To - LvRv*1/temp(x,y,t))
           end do
       end do
   end do
   ```